# Should I use the unit normal to calculate the surface integral?

Tags: surface-integrals

So I am supposed to find the flux through the surface $x^2+y^2 \leq4$ in the xy-plane. So I find the parameterization of the disk:

$r(u,v)=(R cos(\theta), Rsin(\theta),0)$

Then I find the crossproduct $\frac{\partial r}{\partial R} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial u}=(0,0,R)$

So the surface integral is

$
    \iint_S F\bullet(\frac{\partial r}{\partial R} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta})r\,dr\,d \theta$

But in the solution they use $(0,0,1)$, and therefore we don't get the same answer. My book tells me however that when you take surface integrals over vector fields, you don't need the unit normal. You only need to find the unit normal if you take the surface integral over a scalar function. So why I am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parametrize the surface as $ \phi (u, v)$, the surface integral is,

$ \displaystyle \iint_D \vec F \cdot (\phi_u \times \phi_v) ~ du ~ dv \tag1$

$[$Depending on orientation, the normal vector could alternatively be  $(\phi_v \times \phi_u)$$]$

In this case, it is a disk in xy-plane and the parametrization of the surface is,

$\phi (r, t) = (r \cos t, r \sin t, 0), 0 \leq r \leq 2, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$

$\phi_r \times \phi_t = (0, 0, r)$

So following $(1)$, the surface integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \vec F \cdot (0, 0, r) ~ dr ~ dt$

The book instead uses the fact that upward *unit* normal vector to any surface in xy-plane is $(0, 0, 1)$. That leads to surface integral as,

$\displaystyle \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 4} \vec F \cdot (0, 0, 1) ~ dx ~ dy$

Now converting to polar coordinates, the surface integral is

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \vec F \cdot (0, 0, 1) ~ r ~ dr  ~ dt$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I understand it now. I also see that I added an r by mistake in my integral. Because $r(u,v)$ is already expressed in polar coordinates, so I don't need to add the r like I did in $\iint_S F\bullet(\frac{\partial r}{\partial R} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta})r\,dr\,d \theta$. Because I don't need to convert to polar coordinates when $r(u,v)$ already is expressed in polar

Comment: @Mathomat55 yes that's correct.